# retornar json de una peticion fetch en javascript

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Estoy haciendo una petición a una ApiRest con JavaScript, en donde devuelve un JSON de los datos de unas actas por `id`. El resultado de la petición me la muestra en consola normalmente, pero la idea es poder retornarla fuera de la función para pasarla a otra, lo cual, al retornarla da como valor `undefined`.

Este es mi código:

```
function getPk(id) {

  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('id', id);

  var re;

  fetch('http://localhost/DW_MVC_ANGELA/ruteador.php?controller=actas&action=getPk', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      re = result
      console.log('Success:', result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(re['NOMBRES']);
  }, 500);

  return re;
}
```

Para poder retornar el JSON.

Comment: Busca: await fetch.

Answer (score 1):

La función [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) devuelve un objeto que en JavaScript se conoce como [`Promesa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Básicamente este objeto puede devolver un resultado o fallar, de ahí su nombre, que al igual que en la vida real, una promesa puede cumplirse o romperse.

Es común además, que se deba **esperar** por las promesas para saber si se darán o no. Una inconveniencia que presenta la programación para estos casos es que el código no suele esperar, y comúnmente continúa sin esperar a que se completen operaciones que requieren más tiempo del estándar de ejecución.

Es por ello que

```
setTimeout(() =>
{
    console.log(re['NOMBRES']);
},
500);
```

parece funcionar, ya que otorga una espera (500 ms) que aparenta ser suficiente para que termine la promesa antes de imprimir `re['NOMBRES']` por consola. No obstante, esto es más de lo que tardará el código en obtener el valor devuelto de `getPk(id)` y obviamente resultará en un valor por defecto `undefined` que no tuvo tiempo de ser establecido.

---

Afortunadamente, existen algunas formas de esperar a que se complete la promesa para obtener el resultado, como son el uso de [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) o los [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

Propongo un par de ejemplos de guía:

**async / await:**

```js
async function getPk(id)
{
    let url     = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
    let params  = { method: "GET" };
    
    return await fetch(url, params).then(res => res.json())
                                   .then(res => res.data);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () =>
{
    let pk = await getPk(1);
    console.log(pk);
});
```

Aplicado a tu código:

```
async function getPk(id)
{
    let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('id', id);

    let url     = "http://localhost/DW_MVC_ANGELA/ruteador.php?controller=actas&action=getPk";
    let params  = { method: "POST", body: formData };
    
    return await fetch(url, params).then(res => res.json())
                                   .then(res => res.data);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () =>
{
    let pk = await getPk(1);
    console.log(pk);
});
```

**callback:**

Una curiosidad es que `.then((res) => ...)` y `.catch((err) => ...)` son callbacks. Si no te convence el código asincrónico, los callbacks son otra opción.

```js
function getPK(id, sucess, error)
{    
    let url     = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
    let params  = { method: "GET" };
    
    fetch(url, params).then (res  => res.json())
                      .then (res  => sucess(res.data))
                      .catch(err  => error(err));
}

function receptor(pk)
{
    console.log(pk);
}

function error(err)
{
    console.error(err);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
{
  getPK(1, receptor, error);
});
```

Aplicado a tu código:

```
function getPK(id, sucess, error)
{
    let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('id', id);

    let url     = "http://localhost/DW_MVC_ANGELA/ruteador.php?controller=actas&action=getPk";
    let params  = { method: "POST", body: formData };
    
    fetch(url, params).then (res  => res.json())
                      .then (res  => sucess(res.data))
                      .catch(err  => error(err));
}

function receptor(pk)
{
    console.log(pk);
}

function error(err)
{
    console.error(err);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
{
  getPK(1, receptor, error);
});
```